Show/Hide Columns Based on Drop-Down Selection
I followed the instructions in the linked video text.  I practiced following along because I'm trying to apply the same methodology to my workbook.
I have a drop-down list in cell B1 that lists the following options:

The "Cash Payment" data set is in columns D thru H
The "Debit Card Payments" data set is in columns J thru N
The "Credit Card Payments" data set is in columns P thru T

However, when I paste in the code (see below) and select "Cash Payments, Debit Card Payments or Credit Card Payments" from the list in cell B1, all columns from D onward, don't show up.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim PayType As Range
Set PayType = Range("B1")

If Intersect(Target, PayType) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'add as many data sets as required
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range

'add as many headings as you require
Dim FindHdg1 As Range
Dim FindHdg2 As Range
Dim FindHdg3 As Range

'put your headings in the brackets
Set FindHdg1 = Cells.Find("Cash Payments")
Set FindHdg2 = Cells.Find("Debit Card Payments")
Set FindHdg3 = Cells.Find("Credit Card Payments")

Dim ColsToHide As Range
Set ColsToHide = Range("D1:XFD1")

If Intersect(Target, PayType) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'add a case for each option in your drop-down & and add more if required
    Select Case PayType
        Case Is = "All"
            Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            
        Case Is = "Cash Payments"
            Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Set Rng1 = FindHdg1.CurrentRegion
            ColsToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Rng1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        
        Case Is = "Debit Card Payments"
            Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Set Rng2 = FindHdg2.CurrentRegion
            ColsToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Rng2.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        
        Case Is = "Credit Card Payments"
            Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Set Rng3 = FindHdg3.CurrentRegion
            ColsToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Rng3.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select


End Sub



It's difficult know the columns on your screenshot. Please update it to include column heading.

Modify this part of the code
Set FindHdg1 = Cells.Find("Cash Payments", Range("B1"))
Set FindHdg2 = Cells.Find("Debit Card Payments", Range("B1"))
Set FindHdg3 = Cells.Find("Credit Card Payments", Range("B1"))

This is necessary because in the original code search starts from cell A1 and always find cell B1 instead of the one you need. With the mod, Find method will starts after cell B1 and will return the required result.

There are other important parameters i.e. Set FindHdg1 = Cells.Find(What:="Cash Payments", After:=PayType, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows). xlFormulas will find the values even if rows or columns are hidden. xlWhole will match entire cell contents. SearchDirection and MatchCase can be omitted because they are xlNext and False respectively by default.

A Worksheet Change: Show/Hide Columns Based on Drop-Down Selection
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const PAY_TYPE_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B1"
    Const PAY_TYPE_COLUMNS As String = "D:XFD"
    Const PAY_TYPE_ROW As Long = 5

    Dim PayTypes() As Variant: PayTypes = Array( _
        "All", "Cash Payments", "Debit Card Payments", "Credit Card Payments")
    
    Dim payCell As Range: Set payCell = Me.Range(PAY_TYPE_CELL_ADDRESS)
    If Intersect(payCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not changed
    
    Dim PayType As String: PayType = CStr(payCell.Value)
    
    Dim Index As Variant: Index = Application.Match(PayType, PayTypes, 0)
    If IsError(Index) Then
        MsgBox "Unknown pay type """ & PayType & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim payColumns As Range: Set payColumns = Me.Columns(PAY_TYPE_COLUMNS)
    
    If Index = 1 Then ' All
        payColumns.Hidden = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With payColumns.Rows(PAY_TYPE_ROW) ' D5:XFD5
        Index = Application.Match(PayType, .Cells, 0)
        If IsError(Index) Then
            MsgBox "Pay type """ & PayType & """ not found in range """ _
                & .Address(0, 0) & """ of sheet """ & Me.Name & """!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        payColumns.Hidden = True
        .Cells(Index).CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With

End Sub

